# Binding output of Custom Activity designer to activity argument

Tags: wpf, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, custom-activity

I am trying to add a custom activity designer for an activity that I have. The activity looks a little like:

```
public class WaitForUserInputActvitiy : NativeActivity
{
    public InArgument<UserInteractionProperty[]> UserInteraction { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to put a designer on the activity to make it a bit nicer to set these values (so you don't end up typing VB in directly. My designer is based on mindscape property grid. I have an ObservableDictionary source that I want to get the values from and put them in to the InArgument. Currently I am using

```
 private void TestGrid_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    using (ModelEditingScope editingScope = this.ModelItem.BeginEdit())
    {
        Argument myArg = Argument.Create(typeof(WaitForUserInputActvitiy), ArgumentDirection.In);
        this.ModelItem.Properties["UserInteraction"].SetValue(source.Values.ToArray());

        editingScope.Complete();
    }
}
```

However this results in an ArgumentException "Object of type UserInteractionProperty[] cannot be converted to InArgument`1[UserInteractionProperty[]].

So how do I convert my array of UserInteractionProperties into an InArgument?

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit late with an answer here, and I suspect that you found your bug already, because when you cam to writing the code that uses the `UserInteraction` you would have no where to get them from.

So the problem is that `this.ModelItem.Properties["UserInteraction"]` is modeling the `InArgument<UserInteractionProperty[]>` property and you are trying to set it with a value that is `UserInteractionProperty[]`. `InArgument<UserInteractionProperty[]>` is the type to use if you want some other workflow element to supply the list of `UserInteractionProperty`s. It looks like that is not the case though - I suspect that you wanted to declare your property as just a `UserInteractionProperty[]`.

```
public class WaitForUserInputActvitiy : NativeActivity
{
    public UserInteractionProperty[] UserInteraction { get; set; }
}
```

However I would advise declaring it as `Collection<UserInteractionProperty>` since that is nicer.